# Does iframe based application supports the FBJS in page tabs?

Tags: facebook, fbjs

As Facebook announced to support the iframe for page tabs also.
http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/462

I have an existing facebook app built on FBML, and it was working fine until i changed the settings to use the iframe in page tabs.
My app uses FBJS for scripting.

But, now after changing the settings, i noticed FBJS doesn't work with iframe page tabs.

Does anyone facing the similar issue?

-Imran

Comment: I've merged your two unregistered accounts.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's a point in answering a question this old, but I'm fairly certain that you need to replace your FBJS with plain old JavaScript when you switch from FBML to IFRAME.

Comment: Hi Andy, I have already done it. Anyway,Thanks for the answer.